# Why does elasticsearch not use index.routing_partition_size as specified? (custom routing)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, sharding

I'm using custom routing on elasticsearch 8.7.1, and it seems like the routing_partition_size is not being implemented as expected unless I manually specify number_of_routing_shards.

For example, if I do not specify the number_of_routing_shards and use the following settings:
`{ "index": { "number_of_shards": "128", "routing_partition_size": "5", "number_of_replicas": "1" } }`

And then I migrate 1 Million docs with the _routing field, the number of shards that actually end up being used is only 1.

Now if I add the number_of_routing_shards = number_of_shards like this:
`{ "index": { "number_of_shards": "128", "number_of_routing_shards": "128", "routing_partition_size": "5", "number_of_replicas": "1" } }`

Then the right number of shards (5) as specified in the routing_partition_size ends up being used by the routing key on search. Similarly, if I set number_routing_shards = 2*number_of_shards, then the shards used per routing key come out to be routing_partition_size/2.

It looks like there is a connection between number_of_routing_shards and number_of_shards, but I could not find any information online for why this is the case.

I know that the routing formula (when custom routing is used) is as follows:
routing_value = hash(_routing) + hash(_id) % routing_partition_size
shard_num = (routing_value % num_routing_shards) / routing_factor

So why is this the case?

Tried many different configurations, read elasticsearch documentation

Answer (score 0):

When using custom routing in Elasticsearch, the number of routing shards (`number_of_routing_shards`) determines how many shards are used for routing. If you don't specify this setting, only one shard is used for routing regardless of the desired partition size (`routing_partition_size`). To ensure the partition size is implemented correctly, set `number_of_routing_shards` equal to the number of primary shards (`number_of_shards`) in your index. This will ensure the expected number of shards are used for routing based on the specified partition size.

Comment: I see - but this would mean that I will be unable to use the split api later on, right? 

so if i were to make number of shards 128, number_of_routing_shards 512 (so that I can split in the future) and routing_partition_size 20 (with the expectation that 5 shards will be used for routing), would it be a good idea?

Comment: @WorkingMeasurement You are correct. It is recommended to set `number_of_routing_shards` equal to or less than `number_of_shards` to ensure compatibility with the split API in the future. In your case, setting `number_of_shards` to 512, `number_of_routing_shards` to 512 (or lower if needed), and `routing_partition_size` to 20 would be a better approach. This configuration allows for the expected number of routing shards (5) and preserves the option to use the split API later on.

Comment: isn't the number_of_routing_shards supposed to be more or equal to the number of shards because it specifies how many shards we can have post split? For example if my number_of_shards is 128 and number_of_routing_shards is 256, it means I can only split once and make my number of shards 256? After that I am no longer able to split? If I set number of shards = number of routing shards = 128, I will not be able to split at all?

Comment: If you set number_of_shards to 128 and number_of_routing_shards to 256, it means you can perform one split operation and increase the number of shards to 256. However, once you have performed this split, you will not be able to perform additional splits because the number_of_routing_shards would be limited to 256.

Comment: which brings us back to the original question- should I go ahead with this config:
number of shards 128, number_of_routing_shards 512 (so that I can split in the future) and routing_partition_size 20 (with the expectation that 5 shards will be used for routing)?